# Navigating between child routes using Resolve in Angular 2 returns to first child

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

We are using Angular router 4.0.0, and in one of our routes we have implemented router Resolver service in order to provide data to the component when changing the route.

However, when navigating from job/1/items to job/2/items using this.router.navigate (absolute or relative, it doesn't matter), the route temporarly changes to the new one (2) but then returns to the old (1). Notice that error is never reached inside the resolve method implementation in resolve service.

Our routing module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: "", redirectTo: "all", pathMatch:"full"},
            {
                path: "all",
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                component: JobsListComponent,
                data: { title: 'jobs', listId: 'all', listTitle: 'AllJobs' }
            },
            {
                path: ':id',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                component: JobDetailComponent,
                resolve: { detailData: JobDetailResolve },
                children: [
                    { path: '', redirectTo: 'feed', pathMatch: 'full' },
                    { path: 'feed', component: JobDetailFeedComponent, data: { title: 'feed', isDetail: true } },
                    { path: 'items', component: JobDetailItemsComponent, data: { title: 'items', isDetail: true } },

                ]
            },
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    providers: [
        JobDetailResolve
    ]
})
export class JobsRoutingModule { }
```

Our resolve service:

```
@Injectable()
export class JobDetailResolve implements Resolve<JobWithMetadata> {
    constructor(private jobsService: JobsService,
        private router: Router) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<JobWithMetadata> {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            var jobId = route.params["id"];
            this.jobsService.getJob(jobId).subscribe(
                detailData => {
                    var data = new JobWithMetadata(detailData.Job, detailData.JobMetadata, detailData.Job.Number);
                    observer.next(data);
                    observer.complete();
                }, error => {
                    error.subscribe(data => {

                        this.router.navigate([AppRoutes.Home,AppRoutes.Jobs]);
                        observer.next(null);
                        observer.complete();
                    });
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Finally the code inside the component, in this case, is used when clicking a link  inside the child component, goToJob2 is entered: (click)="goToJob2()"

Inside JobDetailItemsComponent we have the above mentioned method:

```
ngOnInit() {
       this.route.data
        .subscribe((data: { detailData: JobWithMetadata }) => {
            this.job = data.detailData.Job;
            this.initComponent();   // refreshes the component data  
        });
  }

goToJob2() {
    this.router.navigate([AppRoutes.Home, AppRoutes.Jobs, "2", "items"]);
}
```

Route first changes to jobs/2/items but somehow it returns to jobs/1/items.

Any advice on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your resolver code you don't need to subscribe to an error.

```
    @Injectable()
    export class JobDetailResolve implements Resolve<JobWithMetadata> {
        constructor(private jobsService: JobsService,
            private router: Router) { }

        resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<JobWithMetadata> {
            return Observable.create(observer => {
                var jobId = route.params["id"];
                this.jobsService.getJob(jobId).subscribe(
                    detailData => {
                        var data = new JobWithMetadata(detailData.Job, detailData.JobMetadata, detailData.Job.Number);
                        observer.next(data);
                        observer.complete();
                    }, error => {
                        error.subscribe(data => {

                            this.router.navigate([AppRoutes.Home,AppRoutes.Jobs]);
                            observer.next(null);
                            observer.complete();
                        });
                    });
            });
        }
    }
```

Reformat your code to

```
@Injectable()
export class JobDetailResolve implements Resolve<JobWithMetadata> {
    constructor(private jobsService: JobsService,
        private router: Router) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<JobWithMetadata> {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            var jobId = route.params["id"];
            this.jobsService.getJob(jobId).subscribe(
                detailData => {
                    var data = new JobWithMetadata(detailData.Job, detailData.JobMetadata, detailData.Job.Number);
                    observer.next(data);
                }, (error) => {
                    if(error) {
                        this.router.navigate([AppRoutes.Home,AppRoutes.Jobs]);
                        observer.next(null);
                        observer.complete();
                    }, () => {
                               observer.complete();
                             });
        });
    }
}
```

If JobService is fetching data using HttpClient then by default that provides a promise / observable so you can subscribe for it in the above way. When you subscribe for error, there is no error observable, the error comes from the http observable itself. Hope this helps.

You also don't need an observable if your service is a http call. Instead you can do

```
@Injectable()

    export class JobDetailResolve implements Resolve<any> {
     constructor(private service: Service) {}
     resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
      return this.service.getJob(route.params["id"]).catch(() => {
        // Navigate here
      });
     }
    }
```

Since observable is an angular promise it will send the data automatically to your route resolver

```
{
                path: ':id',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                component: JobDetailComponent,
                resolve: { detailData: JobDetailResolve },
                children: [
                    { path: '', redirectTo: 'feed', pathMatch: 'full' },
                    { path: 'feed', component: JobDetailFeedComponent, data: { title: 'feed', isDetail: true } },
                    { path: 'items', component: JobDetailItemsComponent, data: { title: 'items', isDetail: true } },

                ]
            }
```